# Excecution of For loop in python 2.7

Tags: python

I encountered this question while doing some beginner level tutorials on python. In my opinion, I  think some times it never get executed, if we try to run something like the following:

```
#1st loop
For i in range (2,2):
     Print i

#2nd loop
For i in range (1,-10):
     Print i
```

These two loop bodies never get executed since it seems already exhausted.

1st loop : when we assign 2 to i,then its already comes to the end.

2nd loop : when assign 1 to i,it cannot proceed further up to -10. since the steps of the increment is 1 , NOT -1.

Am I correct or wrong ? If it is incorrect, why ?

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. If the iterable you are looping over is *empty*, then the `for` loop body is never executed. Both `range(2, 2)` and `range(1, -10)` are *empty sequences*.

Comment: What's preventing you from running this code and seeing for yourself if the `print` is ever executed? (Other than the syntax errors?)

Comment: More examples of empty iterables: `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `""`; those all contain no elements for a `for` loop to iterate over.

Comment: @Rawing: it takes a certain level of confidence and understanding that the fact that `print` is never executed means you understood how the `for` loop work correctly rather than that you have made a different mistake elsewhere..

Comment: I think that although OP is correct, they haven't grasped that `for` loops over an iterable, rather than using a counter as in some other languages - their description of why those loops don't run isn't quite right.

Comment: Something that hasn't been addressed: "assign 1 to i" --- nothing is ever assigned to i, because the iterator produces no values.

Comment: Yes...it's true that 1 doesn't assign to i  but it is mentioned there for the sake of simplicity....it actually means that if the iteration begins with i by assigning 1,then it will get exhausted at the moment without further iterations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those sequences will not be executed.
*The Python for statement iterates over the members of a sequence in order, executing the block each time* (from https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop), so the block will not be executed any time.

And one more remark:
Please, write operators according to Python syntax (namely, not starting with capital):

```
#1st loop
for i in range (2,2):
     print i

#2nd loop
for i in range (1,-10):
     print i
```